# Conditional chain of futures

Tags: scala

I have a sequence of parameters. For each parameter I have to perform DB query, which may or may not return a result. Simply speaking, I need to stop after the first result is non-empty. Of course, I would like to avoid doing unnecessary calls. The caveat is - I need to have this operation(s) contained as a another Future - or any "most reactive" approach. 
Speaking of code:

```
//that what I have
def dbQuery(p:Param): Future[Option[Result]] = {}

//my list of params 
val input = Seq(p1,p2,p3)

//that what I need to implements
def getFirstNonEmpty(params:Seq[Param]): Future[Option[Result]]
```

I know I can possibly just wrap entire function in yet another `Future` and execute code sequentially (Await? Brrr...), but that not the cleanest solution.
Can I somehow create lazy initialized collection of futures, like

```
params.map ( p => FutureWhichWontStartUnlessAskedWhichWrapsOtherFuture { dbQuery(p) }).findFirst(!_.isEmpty())
```

I believe it's possible!

Comment: First thing coming to my mind: `params.toStream.map { p => dbQuery(p) }.dropWhile { f => f.value.isEmpty }.head`

Comment: @VictorMoroz Quoting the `Future.value` ScalaDoc : *If the future is not completed the returned value will be None*. I don't think you want to skip a future just because it is not completed. It will also return a `Result` instead of a `Future[Option[Result]]`.

Comment: Is the parameter sequence ordered? In other words, if both `p1` and `p2` will produce a non-empty result, is it important to use the `p1` result instead of the `p2` result?  If not, you might consider launching all your parameters and grabbing, from the collection of Futures, the first (i.e. fastest) one that returns non-empty.

Comment: @jwvh yes, the order is important and call have to be made in order

Answer (score 1):

What do you think about something like this?

```
def getFirstNonEmpty(params: Seq[Param]): Future[Option[Result]] = {
  params.foldLeft(Future.successful(Option.empty[Result])) { (accuFtrOpt, param) =>
    accuFtrOpt.flatMap {
      case None   => dbQuery(param)
      case result => Future.successful(result)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The only problem is it gets evaluated for every element on the list - so even if the first `dbQuery()` returns, we still iterate over other elements just only to produce `Future.successful(result)`, unpack it and rewrap.

Comment: That's right, the iteration goes to the end of the collection, but there are no more queries executed if the first one returned a result.

Comment: I think this is simple, and prevent unnecessary DB hit, does it matter if it run through whole collections? If you are not doing it a lot or having a really long list of params it's probably alright

Answer (score 1):

This might be overkill, but if you are open to using scalaz we can do this using [`OptionT`](https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/repositories/releases/archive/org/scalaz/scalaz_2.11/7.2.3/scalaz_2.11-7.2.3-javadoc.jar/!/index.html#scalaz.OptionT) and `foldMap`.

With `OptionT` we sort of combine `Future` and `Option` into one structure. We can get the first of two `Future`s with a non-empty result using `OptionT.orElse`.

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

val someF: Future[Option[Int]] = Future.successful(Some(1))
val noneF: Future[Option[Int]] = Future.successful(None)

val first = OptionT(noneF) orElse OptionT(someF)
first.run // Future[Option[Int]] = Success(Some(1))
```

We could now get the first non-empty `Future` from a `List` with `reduce` from the standard library (this will however run all the `Future`s) :

```
List(noneF, noneF, someF).map(OptionT.apply).reduce(_ orElse _).run
```

But with a `List` (or other collection) we can't be sure that there is at least one element, so we need to use `fold` and pass a start value. Scalaz  can do this work for us by using a `Monoid`. The `Monoid[OptionT[Future, Int]]` we will use will supply the start value and combine the `Future`s with the `orElse` used above.

```
type Param = Int
type Result = Int
type FutureO[x] = OptionT[Future, x]

def query(p: Param): Future[Option[Result]] = 
  Future.successful{ println(p); if (p > 2) Some(p) else None }

def getFirstNonEmpty(params: List[Param]): Future[Option[Result]] = {
  implicit val monoid = PlusEmpty[FutureO].monoid[Result]
  params.foldMap(p => OptionT(query(p))).run
}

val result = getFirstNonEmpty(List(1,2,3,4))
// prints 1, 2, 3
result.foreach(println) // Some(3)
```

Comment: The problem with `List(noneF, noneF, someF).map(OptionT.apply).reduce(_ orElse _).run` is that it will always run all the futures, regardless of returner value, just try to use `List(someF, someF, someF)`

Comment: Hmm, looks like there is similar problem like the other answer - Function, in fact, iterates over entire input, does not evaluate `p => OptionT(query(p))` more than necessary, however still creates it.

Comment: @M4ks You are right about the one using `reduce`, but the `foldMap` one doesn't create the other `Future`s right ?

Comment: It does not evaluate the function, right, but still the final `orElse` is called for every elements despite finding the non-empty one.

Comment: @M4ks Yes, but that will always be the case if you use something like `fold` in Scala and just executing `orElse` a few times extra will probably be peanuts compared to the `Future` itself.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but if someone comes looking for an answer, here is my take. I solved it for a use case that required me to loop through a limited number of futures sequentially and stop when the first of them returned a result.

I did not need a library for my use-case, a light-weight combination of recursion and pattern matching was sufficient. Although the question here does not have the same problem as a sequence of futures, looping through a sequence of parameters would be similar.

Here would be the pseudo-code based on recursion.

I have not compiled this, fix the types being matched/returned.

```
def getFirstNonEmpty(params: Seq[Param]): Future[Option[Result]] = {
    if (params.isEmpty) {
      Future.successful(None)
    } else {
      val head = params.head
      dbQuery(head) match {           
         case Some(v) => Future.successful(Some(v)) 
         case None => getFirstNonEmpty(params.tail)          
      }
    }
}
```